# Running PHP script in background

Tags: php

I am testing a php script that has been developed on an OS-X system at Debian and it behaves different there.

To reproduce it I wrote two scripts: parent.php and child.php:

parent.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo "parent started...\n";
shell_exec(__DIR__ . '/child.php &2>/dev/null &');
echo "parent finished.\n";
```

child.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo "child started...\n";
sleep(5);
echo "child finished.\n";
```

Running parent.php on OS-X I get back imediately the two output lines (parent started, parent finished). On Debian I get the "parent started..." line, then a delay of 5 seconds an then the "parent finished.". Running "./child.php &2>/dev/null &" in the shell gives me back the prompt imediately as expected. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: While I'm sure it's just a shorthand I've never seen before, since you say it works, I usually write that exec line as `{cmd} > /dev/null 2>&1 &` - would be interested to know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you mean to suppress errors by `&2>/dev/null` or just want to suppress any output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `&2>` part. It may not be supported in all systems. Also in every shell (bash, sh, ksh etc).

Try this,

```
 exec("/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/php /path/to/child.php 2> /dev/null' &");
```

If you want to suppress all the output use this,

```
 exec("/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/php /path/to/child.php &> /dev/null ' &");
```

[BASH-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Just tested, `exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/child.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &")` should work too.

Comment: Your last line is missing the `&` on the end to separate the child process from the parent

Comment: @dave Thanks. Missed it as I typed too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php) or [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.system.php) instead of shell_exec, maybe shell_exec has not the same behavior on different OS.